# google run - does each container instance get 443, if that is what I need

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to understand google run to deploy docker containers on demand. I may have load balancer at 443 and all that, but assume without load balancer will I be able to get 443 for all say 10s or 100s or instances? Thanks!

Comment: It is with respect to google run (as in google cloud functions.)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you want to set up a load balancer in front of CLoud Run? Do you serve https endpoint from your container? What's your pain piont?

Comment: There is no load balancer. All the instances of docker container need to be mapped to 443. Let me give an example, if I use a physical machine, and say I have 5 instances of  the internal docker image running on it, I can choose any port inside docker, but when I map it to the physical machine, I can use 443 only to the first one, [ports: "443:443"] other will need to be mapped to some other port on the physical machine because 443 is already taken by the first instance mapping (one IP address on the physical machine will have only one 443, not complicating with many IPs). continued below...

Comment: (continued from above...) So I plan to use "google run" to instantiate say 10 (or multiple instances) can each of the 10 container instance be mapped to port 443 to the outside world. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's serverless! It's mysterious and powerful!! In fact, on only have to worry about your code (here, your container with Cloud Run). You have to host a webserver (in HTTP (by default on the port 8080 but you can change it), not HTTPS) that answer to HTTP requests. That's all!!

Then deploy it. The deployment create a service and a revision. Each new deployment, create a new revision (set of container + param unique, like this, if your new container and/or the new params of the new revision break your service, you can easily rollback to a previous stable revision).

When you serve traffic, Cloud Run is behind GFE (Google Front End). A Google wide proxy in charge of SSL management (that's why you don't have to worry about HTTPS in your container) and to route the traffic to your Cloud Run revisions. Here, Cloud Run engine is in charge of the instance creation (because Cloud Run scale to 0), and the loadbalancing of the traffic between all the created instances. You have nothing to do, it's native.

So, take it easy, that's the future for the developers!